# jqxscrollview of jqwidgets do not display scrollview buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I use the
[jqxscrollview](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxscrollview/index.htm#demos/jqxscrollview/defaultfunctionality.htm) of jqwidgets to display images scrolling.

I can't figure out why I don't see the scrollview buttons. I tried to force `showButtons` to `true` but nothing.

```
$('#photoGallery').jqxScrollView({ width: 680, height: 450,
     showButtons: true, buttonsOffset: [0, 0]});        // Create a jqxScrollView
$('#photoGallery').jqxScrollView({ slideShow: true });  // lance le slide shom
```

See the web site and its source code on:
https://aagee.dz/icaee2024/sba.php

Thanks